# Collapsible menu is too long for mobile landscape

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with a collapsible menu I created in Bootstrap 3. It works great until its viewed in landscape from a mobile device. When you expand the menu in landscape, the links drop down farther than the viewport. That wouldn't be a problem, but the menu is fixed to the top, meaning the user cannot scroll down to see the hidden links bellow. Whenever the user scrolls, the menu stays put and the elements behind the fixed navbar move (though you cannot see it move because of the menu overlay). Here is a pic:

[image: landscape view from iphone]

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">                          
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>         
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">      
                <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                    <li><a id="navHistory" class="history" href="#">History</a></li>
                    <li><a id="navEvents" class="events" href="#">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a id="navSponsors" class="sponsors" href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
                    <li><a id="navEntertainment" class="entertainment" href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                    <li><a id="navGallery" class="gallery" href="#">Gallery</a></li>            
                    <li><a id="navContact" class="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>     
                </ul>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--Navbar End-->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner {
    height: 95px;
    background-image: url('../img/top_red.png');
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner .container {
    background-color: #d0112b;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'sanchezregular';
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #d0112b;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .navbar .nav > li > a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I tried to set the .nav-justified container to have a max-width of 100%, but I'm still unable to make these links fit or at least scroll. Has anyone else has this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Csn you please post the corresponding css code for your navbar?

Comment: try adding `overflow-y: auto;` to `collapse.navbar-collapse.navHeaderCollapse` that will enable the users to scroll

Comment: Added CSS. Orlo, I thought this would have worked, but unfortunately it didn't. I also tried to add overflow to nav-justified without any success :/

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question, but maybe my answer can help to someone.

Bootstrap adds to .navbar-collapse.collapse the media query:
**@media(min-width: 768px) { overflow:visible!important }** which can block scrolling menu on landscape mode.
BUT!
If you are using the correct viewport meta tag with “width=device-width” you shouldn’t have this issue, because then **.navbar-collapse.in { overflow-y: auto }** is applied by bootstrap on mobile landscape.

It happens, because media queries depend from viewport declaration.
It can be pretty confusing, so right now I’m just telling, I have temporary two type of responsive header with bootstrap collapsing navbar (for some reason), one of them uses the correct viewport meta tag: “width=viewport-width, initial-scale=1”, the other uses the “uncorrect”: “initial-scale=0.5”  WITHOUT  “width=viewport-width”. (It is stupid, I know but I have to solve something right now, and I have to keep the desktop appearance on mobile on some pages…)

The important part is to understand that bootstrap added media queries can work correctly with correct viewport meta tag.

I hope I could help, I could tell much more, but it relates more to viewport and media queries connection.
This can help for understanding:
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html

Answer (score 0):

"overflow-y: auto; overflow: hidden;" - will enable the users to scroll.

For the DIV to expand 100% of the viewport, you should set "position: absolute" and height to 100%

```
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lem5z/3/

Comment: This works to an extent. The overflow works, but the .navbar-inner div will not expand past the 95px set height. What really needs to happen is the div needs to expand 100% of the viewport. If the viewport is too small to fit the menu options, thats when the overflow will kick in. I tried setting .navbar-inner to 100% height, but still had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, adding this CSS to the `<ul>` of the navbar

```
max-height: 85vh;
```

fixes this issue.

It creates 2 (or more) columns if the smartphone is in landscape mode and the bootstrap navbar is too tall for the screen